# How can I optimize my cosine similarity function that compares row values between two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow2.0

I am attempting to calculate the cosine similarity between a title and search query that are stored within a pandas dataframe, but am struggling to find the optimal method. It runs very slowly and I feel there must be a better way.

My code looks like:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import tensorflow_text

# Load Google universal sentence encoder for semantic similarity 
USE = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-large/3")

# Load title and search queries from a test file
data = pd.read_json('1.json')

def use_filter(data, min_sim=0.80):
        """Utilize google universal sentence encoder to compare similarity between title and query 
        and then flter dataframe based on cosine similarirt 
        Args:
            data(Dataframe): Dataframe of clicklog data pre-filtered for low similarity 
            min_sim (float): minim level of similarity to keep output 
        Returns:
            df(Dataframe): Dataframe of clicklog data filtered for low similarity 
        """
        x = []
        compare = dict(zip(data['title'], data['query']))
        
        for key, value in compare.items():
            for i in value:
                cos_sim = cosine_similarity(embed_fn([key]), embed_fn([i])).flatten()[0]
                x.append(cos_sim)
        
        data['cos'] = x 
        data = data[data['cos'] > min_sim]
        
        return data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Here is a [list of options to calculate cosine similarity quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17627219).

You can also speed up the process by [calculating the cosine similarities all at once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32688866) (instead of one by one).

Alternatively, if you are willing to sacrifice a little bit of accuracy for speed, you can try approximate methods. Some of the most common ones are:

- Spotify's [Annoy](https://github.com/spotify/annoy)
- [Hnswlib](https://github.com/nmslib/hnswlib)
- Google's [ScaNN](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/tree/master/scann)

Comment: Thank You very much for the resources. I have figured it out with your assistance.